# Using TinyMCE4 How Can I Disable All ShortCut Keys

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE4 to wrap a textarea for some basic text editor functionality. However, TinyMCE4 has default shortcut keys. I need to disable these shortcut keys as they interfere with some global hotkeys on the system I am creating.

Does anyone know how I can disable all of the hotkeys in TinyMCE4? Ideally I want it to not handle them at all so I can have the code on the parent level intercept the hotkeys.

The main issue is that I have ctrl+a being mapped to open a modal window but TinyMCE is forcing it to be select all (yes I know ctrl+a is standard, it was not my choice haha).

For my javascript library I am loading everything using a KnockoutJS binding (also a requirement). Please see the source below for my current attempt, the attempt at removing them occurs in the .on('init') function.

Thanks.

```
`//This gets called and works properly. In my code it contains all my custom bindings.
function RegisterBindings() {

    ko.bindingHandlers.tinymce = GetTinyMCEBinding();
    ko.virtualElements.allowedBindings['tinymce'] = true;
    ko.expressionRewriting._twoWayBindings['tinymce'] = true;

}

//Get the binding for the TinyMCE WYSWIG Library
function GetTinyMCEBinding() {
    var binding, cache, cacheInstance, configure, writeValueToProperty;
    cache = "";
    cacheInstance = null;
    binding = {
        after: ["attr", "value"],
        defaults: {},
        extensions: {},
        init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var $element, ext, options, settings;
            $element = $(element);
            options = (allBindings.has("tinymceConfig") ? allBindings.get("tinymceConfig") : null);
            ext = (allBindings.has("tinymceExtensions") ? allBindings.get("tinymceExtensions") : []);
            settings = configure(binding["defaults"], ext, options, arguments);
            $element[$element.is('input, textarea') ? 'text' : 'html'](ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
            setTimeout((function () {
                $element.tinymce(settings);
            }), 0);
            ko.utils["domNodeDisposal"].addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
                var tinymce;
                tinymce = $(element).tinymce();
                if (tinymce) {
                    tinymce.remove();
                }
                if (tinymce === cacheInstance) {
                    cacheInstance = null;
                }
            });

            return {
                controlsDescendantBindings: true
            };
        },
        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
            var tinymce, value;
            tinymce = $(element).tinymce();
            value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
            if (value === null) {
                value = "";
            }
            if (tinymce && !(cacheInstance === tinymce && cache === value)) {
                cacheInstance = tinymce;
                cache = value;
                if (tinymce.getContent() !== value) {
                    tinymce.setContent(value);
                }
            }
        }
    };
    writeValueToProperty = function (property, allBindings, key, value, checkIfDifferent) {
        var propWriters;
        if (!property || !ko.isObservable(property)) {
            propWriters = allBindings.get('_ko_property_writers');
            if (propWriters && propWriters[key]) {
                return propWriters[key](value);
            }
        } else if (ko.isWriteableObservable(property) && (!checkIfDifferent || property.peek() !== value)) {
            return property(value);
        }
    };
    configure = function (defaults, extensions, options, args) {
        var applyChange, config, setup, applyShortcuts;
        config = $.extend(true, {}, defaults);
        if (options) {
            ko.utils.objectForEach(options, function (property) {
                if (Object.prototype.toString.call(options[property]) === "[object Array]") {
                    if (!config[property]) {
                        config[property] = [];
                    }
                    options[property] = ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(config[property].concat(options[property]));
                }
            });
            $.extend(true, config, options);
        }
        if (!config["plugins"]) {
            config["plugins"] = ["paste"];
        } else {
            if ($.inArray("paste", config["plugins"]) === -1) {
                config["plugins"].push("paste");
            }
        }
        applyChange = function (editor) {
            editor.on("change keyup nodechange", function (e) {
                return setTimeout((function () {
                    var name, value;
                    value = editor.getContent();
                    cache = value;
                    cacheInstance = editor;
                    writeValueToProperty(args[1](), args[2], "tinymce", value);
                    for (name in extensions) {
                        if (extensions.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                            binding["extensions"][extensions[name]](editor, e, args[2], args[4]);
                        }
                    }
                }), 0);
            });

            editor.on("init", function (e) {
                return setTimeout((function () {
                    //FORCE REMOVAL OF TINYMCE SHORTCUT KEYS TO PREVENT INTERFERENCE WITH OUT HOTKEYS
                    // Note these lists may not be complete & that other tinymce plugins can add their own shortcuts anyway.
                    var ctrls = ['a', 'b', 'i', 'u', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'z', 'y,ctrl+shift+z', 's', 'k', 'Alt+F', 'P'];
                    var modKeys = ['c', 'r', 'l', 'j', 'q', 'u', 'o', 'n', 's', 'm', 'z', 't', 'd', 'h', 'o', 'x', 'a', 'w'];
                    // Overwrite shortcuts with no-op function. Key sequences will still be captured.
                    for (var i = 0; i < ctrls.length; i++) {
                        var sCutMeta = 'meta+' + ctrls[i];
                        var sCutCtrl = 'ctrl+' + ctrls[i];
                        editor.addShortcut(sCutMeta, '', function () { });
                        editor.addShortcut(sCutCtrl, '', function () { });
                    }
                    for (var i = 0; i < modKeys.length; i++) {
                        var sCutAccess = 'access+' + modKeys[i];
                        var sCutAltShift = 'alt+shift+' + modKeys[i];
                        editor.addShortcut(sCutAltShift, '', function () { });
                        editor.addShortcut(sCutAccess, '', function () { });
                    }
                }), 0);
            });
        };

        if (typeof config["setup"] === "function") {
            setup = config["setup"];
            config["setup"] = function (editor) {
                setup(editor);
                applyChange(editor);
                applyShortcuts(editor);
            };
        } else {
            config["setup"] = applyChange;
        }
        return config;
    };
    return binding;
}
```

`

Comment: Looks like this might work: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/168044/31339

Comment: Thanks for the info but unfortunately not. You can see I have done essentially the same idea but with more shortcut combos in my editor.on("init") function. I actually copied part of the not working code form the answer you provided.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out? I have the same issue and the answer provided above doesn't work for me either.